# Not finding image source properly despite giving the correct path in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm stuck with a problem. I Have Worked on images before in html but there never seemed to be a problem. I'm partially working on a project and I am giving the right path to the folder but the image is just not showing up. All the images had the same problem. Here is my code Snippet:

```
<div class="grid-col grid-col-12">
                            <div class="item-instructor bg-color-1">
                                <a href="page-profile.html" class="instructor-avatar">
                                    <img src="UniLearn/UniLearn%20(with%20Options%20Panel)/img/saif.jpg" alt="">
                                </a>
                                <div class="info-box">
                                    <h3>M Saifur Rahman</h3>
                                    <span class="instructor-profession">Director,Business Development</span>

                                    <div class="divider"></div>


<center><button type="button" class="btn btn info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Read More</button></center>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: black;">M Saifur Rahman</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="biography-image">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/210x220" align="left">
            </div>
           <div class="biography-info">
                 <p>
</p>    

           </div> 

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>




                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-instructor bg-color-3">
                                <a href="page-profile.html" class="instructor-avatar">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/210x220" alt="">
                                </a>
                                <div class="info-box">
                                    <h3>Bijon Islam</h3>
                                    <span class="instructor-profession">CEO</span>
                                    <div class="divider"></div>


<center><button type="button" class="btn btn info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Read More</button></center>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: black;">Bijon Islam</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="biography-image">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/210x220" align="left">
                            </div>
           <div class="biography-info">
            <p></p>
           </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-col grid-col-12">
                            <div class="item-instructor bg-color-2">
                                <a href="page-profile.html" class="instructor-avatar">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/210x220" data-at2x="http://placehold.it/210x220" alt>
                                </a>

                                <div class="info-box">
                                    <h3>Ivdad Ahmed Khan Mojlish</h3>
                                    <span class="instructor-profession">Managing director</span>
                                    <div class="divider"></div>
        <center><button type="button" class="btn btn info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Read More</button></center>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: black;">Ivdad Ahmed Khan Mojlish</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="biography-image">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/210x220" align="left">
                            </div>
            <div class="biography-info">
                <p></p>     
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-instructor bg-color-6">
                                <a href="page-profile.html" class="instructor-avatar">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/210x220" data-at2x="http://placehold.it/210x220" alt>
                                </a>
                                <div class="info-box">
                                    <h3>Zahedul Amin</h3>
                                    <span class="instructor-profession">Directory,Finance & Strategy</span>
                                    <div class="divider"></div>
                                            <center><button type="button" class="btn btn info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Read More</button></center>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: black;">Zahedul Amin</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="biography-image">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/210x220" align="left">
                            </div>
          <div class="biography-image">

            <p></p> 
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My htdocs path is like this:
F:\xampp\htdocs\Main Files\UniLearn\UniLearn (with Options Panel)\img

Comment: what is the Path of the Html Doc itself??

how do you browse your work??
do you use just a web browser or a web server like IIS.

Comment: F:\xampp\htdocs\Main Files\UniLearn\UniLearn (with Options Panel)\img ..working in  google chrome

Comment: if so then your HTML document is at the same path as the Image so you just need to put the SRC as the name of the image 

         src='saif.jpg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother, i think the problem is in the paths, you have here 3 choices base on your HTML page location:-

- if the .html file is in the same folder with the image your code should be like this:

  ```
  <a href="page-profile.html" class="instructor-avatar">
      <img src="saif.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  ```

(.html page beside saif.jpg)

- if the .html file is in a folder contains the folder of the image your code should be like this:

  ```
  <a href="page-profile.html" class="instructor-avatar">
      <img src="UniLearn/UniLearn (with Options Panel)/img/saif1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  ```

(.html page beside the folder UniLearn)

- if the .html is in a different folder you need to jump up levels till you reach the nearest common folder and point to the image code should be like this:

  ```
  <a href="page-profile.html" class="instructor-avatar">
      <img src="../../UniLearn/UniLearn (with Options Panel)/img/saif2.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  ```

  (.html is in a path two levels far from UniLearn)

-->(../..) Means go up two levels in the folder structure.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in your directory name spaces.
try to take picture from other directory then you will see what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the spacing. if you want to keep the naming (not recommended) and still use the image try this:

```
<img src="UniLearn/UniLearn%20(with%20Options%20Panel)/img/saif.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: I tried this and this absolutely distorted the structure

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell with only this information.

Here's how to troubleshoot this:

First replace all spaces with `%20` this is the way to url encode those characters.

If it still is a problem (normally browsers auto url encode), compare the URL you are using to access the website, the href in the `base` tag if there is one, and the url of the image. The browser will use those 3 together to figure out the final URL...

You can right click on the picture, and open in a new tab. It will allow you to rapidly see the URL that is used to point to the picture and allow you to make changes.

Also, since you are on a unix machine, the case is important. Make sure that all capitals should be present.